# Add owner's username to Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have a model, `Playlist`, which `belongs_to` a `User`. Instead of the routes for playlists to be

```
/playlists
/playlists/new
/playlists/:id
/playlists/:id/edit
```

I would like them to be

```
/:username/playlists
/:username/playlists/new
/:username/:playlist_slug
/:username/:playlist_slug/edit
```

But, this has to still work:

```
playlist_path(@playlist)
# NOT: playlist_path(@playlist.user, @playlist)
```

Since the user of the path is `@playlist.user`. It is not DRY to repeat this parameter every time I need a path. Besides, it is a risk, since it allows for bogus calls. For example `playlist_path(@alice, @bob.playlists.first)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking for
[Friendly id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) is its implementation.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[`FriendlyID`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is what you want:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "", only: [] do
   resources :playlists #-> url.com/:user_id/playlists
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :playlists

   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will automatically populate the `paths` and `.find` methods with the *slug* value for your `@user`:

```
#view
<%= link_to @playlist.name, user_playlist_path(@user, @playlist) %>

#app/controllers/playlists_controller.rb
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user     = User.find params[:user_id]
      @playlist = @user.playlists.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

--

As per the [FriendlyID docs](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart), you'll need to do the following to get it set up:

```
rails generate friendly_id #-> initializer
rails generate scaffold user name:string slug:string:uniq
rake db:migrate
```

You'll also want to update your `User` model to ensure that each record has a `slug`:

```
$ rails c
$ User.find_each(&:save)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I haven't found a way to use FriendlyId to help me turn `user_playlist_path(@user, @playlist)` to `user_playlist_path(@playlist)`.

Comment: Well it's not `friendly_id` you'd need for that. If you're wanting to scope the path for *one* user, you'll want to hard-code it into your routes or use `current_user` in the controller. If you give me some more context, I'll write an update for you